# Where Does the Server Git Username Show Up on GitHub.com?

Tags: git, github

To set my username in my webserver, I do:

```
git config --global user.name "GTS Joe"
```

For my email address, I go:

```
git config --global user.email "my@email.com"
```

My question is, where do I see these settings take effect on github.com? I have a couple of repos I've pushed live but don't see my server username there, all I see is my github.com username. So what does git config --global user.name "GTS Joe" do that can be viewed on github.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`user.name` is the display name that will be shown on commits, as is `user.email`. However, Github displays your Github username instead of the commit `user.name` when `user.email` matches some registered user email.

If you push a commit with a non-registered email (i.e. a dummy one), it will instead display `user.name` you set *and* will not be a link to the user account.